# When is it okay to switch statements in an OO language supporting polymorphism?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, switch-statement

Lets say I have a method like this :

```
public void sketch(Shape shape){
 switch(shape.getType){
   case CIRCLE: 
      Circle circle = (Circle)shape;
      circle.drawCircle();
      break;
   case RECTANGLE: 
      Rectangle rectangle= (Rectangle)shape;
      rectangle.drawRectanle();
      break;  

  }
}
```

The above code can be easily refactored by having an `Shape` interface that knows how to draw itself. Then concrete classes like `Circle` and `Rectangle` will implement `draw()`.
The above client code then becomes as given below (way more readable and uncluttered than the previous snippet):

```
public void sketch(Shape shape){
   shape.draw();   
}
```

So my question is regarding the usages of *switch* in a OO language that supports *polymorphism*. Is it *always* considered an anti-pattern? Is there any situation when *switches* can become a life saver?